# .Net Mongo driver error: Connection reset by peer

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

The microservice is running on k8s cluster. It uses multiple threads to read some data from MongoDB.
Pod is restarting with this error:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer."," 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer","
```

This is the error:

```json
{ "t":{"$date":"2023-05-30T04:19:24.103+03:00"},
  "s":"I", 
  "c":"NETWORK", 
  "id":22989, 
  "ctx":"conn658382",
  "msg":"Error sending response to client. Ending connection from remote",
  "attr":{
    "error":{
       "code":6,
       "codeName":"HostUnreachable",
       "errmsg":"Connection reset by peer"}, 
    "remote":"ip",
    "connectionId":658382}}
```

MongoDB Server 6.0
.Net 6
MongoDB Driver 2.19

How to solve this issue?
I have tried increase connection pool, etc.

Comment: You need to look at the log of the MongoDb server (mongodb it self and the server logs). That is the one that closes the connection so its log will probably tell you why it did so.

Comment: Is it always, or just occasionally? If it's just very occasionally it seems like a transient failure and I don't think much can really be done about it beyond implementing retries and circuit breakers, etc. Networks aren't perfect, after all.

Comment: It's always. It happens wher background process working some time. Every time when it started. There is no problem on local machine

Comment: {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-30T04:19:24.103+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22989,   "ctx":"conn658382","msg":"Error sending response to client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":6,"codeName":"HostUnreachable","errmsg":"Connection reset by peer"},
"remote":"ip","connectionId":658382}}